# Request Payload in a POST request

Tags: php, post, request, screen-scraping, payload

I am trying to scrape a PHP website and instead of Form Data i am seeing Payload requests in Header Section. What is a Payload Request? I am using Developer Tools from Chrome to analyse the Data.

For example:

```
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryWEXJCV0v7CwVqn0X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Command"

-1
------WebKitFormBoundaryWEXJCV0v7CwVqn0X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name_1"

12
------WebKitFormBoundaryWEXJCV0v7CwVqn0X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pass_1"

34
------WebKitFormBoundaryWEXJCV0v7CwVqn0X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="logins"

Î•Î¯ÏƒÎ¿Î´Î¿Ï‚
------WebKitFormBoundaryWEXJCV0v7CwVqn0X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
```

All i want to do is scrape a website which requires username and password.

```
My code is this:
function get_data_with_post_fields($url, $fields_data) {

      $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 5;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ""); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_data);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}






$url_to_scrape = 'http://www.awebsite.com/index.php?com=products&id=10000';




                $PF = "&name_1=xxx&pass_1=xxx";



        print $raw = get_data_with_post_fields($url_to_scrape,$PF);
```

How should i form my POST REQUEST? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You see that in the header section of what? The request? The response? Either way doesn't make sense.

Comment: The Request Payload appears in the middle of request section and the response section as if it belongs to nowhere. So i have: 1. Request Header 2. Request Payload 3. Response Header

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?